# False warning in a simple hello world

Tags: rust

I started studying Rust and made a very simple hello world, but it's giving me a `warning: value assigned to name is never read`

Why is this warning happening even though the variable `name` is being used in the `println` macro?

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = "hello";
    name = "world";
    println!("{}", name);
}
```

Will work without the `warning` if I use `name = "hello"` before changing it, like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = "hello";
    println!("{}", name);
    name = "world";
    println!("{}", name);
}
```

Comment: The first assignment (`"hello"`) is immediately overwritten by the second without being used. I guess the line number in the error message refers to this line.